# How to workaround a memory leak in a vendor's DLL being used in Python?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, ctypes, loadlibrary

I'm using a vendor's C API for a piece of business software by loading their library using Python's ctypes module.

After deploying the software I wrote, I found that the vendor's library leaks memory on a consistent and predictable basis, according to the number of calls of a certain function that's part of their API.

I even duplicated the leak in a C program that uses no heap allocations.

I contacted the vendor about the issue, and they said they're working on it, but I probably can't realistically expect a fix until the next version of the software.

I had the idea of reloading the vendor's dll after a certain threshold of calls to the leaking function, but this did not release the leaked memory.

I found that I could force the library to unload like so:

```
_ctypes.FreeLibrary(vendor_dll._handle)
```

This frees the memory, but causes the interpreter to crash seemingly randomly after a number of minutes of using the vendor's API.

I found this issue in the Python bug tracker that describes my situation:
https://bugs.python.org/issue14597

It seems that if there's still an open reference to the library, forcing it to unload will inevitably crash the Python interpreter.

Worst case scenario, I'm thinking I could load the vendor's library in a separate process, proxy requests using a multiprocessing Queue, and setup a watchdog to recreate the process if the interpreter dies.

Is there a better way to work around this?

Comment: I suppose a more elegant solution to my above workaround would be to exit and relaunch the worker process on a regular interval. This would allow the memory leaked by the vendor's library to free, but wouldn't crash the interpreter.

Comment: If freeing the library works, then it's not really a memory leak. The library must be tracking these allocations to free them on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. As to unloading `vendor_dll`, you should first remove all references to the current instance and ensure nothing executes its code again, including outstanding asynchronous callbacks. Then you can unload and reload the DLL. Shared libraries are reference counted, so to ensure it's actually unloaded, call `FreeLibrary` until it raises an `OSError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I fixed the issue by loading the vendor's library in a separate process, and accessing it through Pyro4, like so:

```
class LibraryWorker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.library = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(
            'vendor_library.dll')

        Pyro4.serveSimple(
            {self, 'library'},
            ns=False)

    def lib_func(self):
        res = self.library.func()
        return res
```

It was a bit of extra work to massage the old code to not pass ctypes pointers between the two processes, but it works.

With the library loaded in a separate process, I can keep track of the memory usage. When it gets too high, I can terminate and recreate the process to free the memory.

Comment: Sorry, do you have a full example of using pyro for communication between processes in one app? Somehow, I can't make it work.